# JOGL correct light and reflection in spheres

Tags: java, windows, opengl, graphics, jogl

I'm trying to get the lights and reflection correct in my program. I have a big sphere, which I can move the the mouse, that should be a light source (LIGHT0), and smaller spheres bouncing around that should reflect the light. I also need a directional light that I can change the direction using the keyboard

first some colors I defined:

```
float whitish[] = {0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 1};
float white[] = {1, 1, 1, 1};
float blackish[] = {0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1};
float black[] = {0, 0, 0, 1}
```

I create the directional light with

```
gl.glLightfv(GL.GL_LIGHT1, GL.GL_AMBIENT, blackish,0);
gl.glLightfv(GL.GL_LIGHT1, GL.GL_SPECULAR, white,0);
gl.glLightfv(GL.GL_LIGHT1, GL.GL_DIFFUSE, white,0);
gl.glLightfv(GL.GL_LIGHT1, GL.GL_POSITION, spot_position,0);
```

spot_position is initially [ 0, 0, 1, 0] but it can change by pressing the keyboard keys. a key press adds 0.05 to a specific component of the position vector, until it reaches 1, then it resets back to -1 (nothing fancy).

The light of the center sphere is:

```
gl.glLightfv(GL.GL_LIGHT0, GL.GL_POSITION, position,0);
gl.glLightfv(GL.GL_LIGHT0, GL.GL_AMBIENT, blackish,0);
gl.glLightfv(GL.GL_LIGHT0, GL.GL_DIFFUSE, white,0);
gl.glLightfv(GL.GL_LIGHT0, GL.GL_SPECULAR, white,0);
```

This light's position is always centered inside my big transparent sphere. w component of the position vector is 1.

I have this code to draw the picture in the back

```
gl.glBegin(GL_QUADS);
gl.glMaterialfv(GL.GL_FRONT, GL.GL_DIFFUSE, white,0);
gl.glMaterialfv(GL.GL_FRONT, GL.GL_SPECULAR, white,0);
gl.glMaterialfv(GL.GL_FRONT, GL.GL_SHININESS, white,0);
// Back Face
gl.glNormal3f(0, 0, 1);
gl.glTexCoord2f(texRight, texBottom);
gl.glVertex3f(rx2, ry1, rz1);
gl.glTexCoord2f(texRight, texTop);
gl.glVertex3f(rx2, ry2, rz1);
gl.glTexCoord2f(texLeft, texTop);
gl.glVertex3f(rx1, ry2, rz1);
gl.glTexCoord2f(texLeft, texBottom);
gl.glVertex3f(rx1, ry1, rz1);
```

To draw the spheres, I use the following functions:

```
public void drawtriangle(float[] v1, float[] v2, float[] v3) {
    gl.glBegin(GL.GL_TRIANGLES);
    gl.glNormal3fv(v1, 0);
    gl.glVertex3fv(v1, 0);
    gl.glNormal3fv(v2, 0);
    gl.glVertex3fv(v2, 0);
    gl.glNormal3fv(v3, 0);
    gl.glVertex3fv(v3, 0);
    gl.glEnd();
}

private void subdivideSphere2(float v1[], float v2[], float v3[], long depth) {
   float v12[] = new float[3];
   float v23[] = new float[3];
   float v31[] = new float[3];
    int i;

    if (depth==0) {
    float[] color= {v1[0]*v1[0], v2[1]*v2[1], v3[2]*v3[2], alpha};
    gl.glMaterialfv(GL.GL_FRONT, GL.GL_AMBIENT, blackish,0);
    gl.glMaterialfv(GL.GL_FRONT, GL.GL_DIFFUSE, color,0);
    gl.glMaterialfv(GL.GL_FRONT, GL.GL_SPECULAR, color,0);
    gl.glMaterialfv(GL.GL_FRONT, GL.GL_SHININESS, color,0);
      drawtriangle(v1, v2, v3);
      return;
    }
   for (i = 0; i<3; i++) {
       v12[i] = v1[i]+v2[i];
       v23[i] = v2[i]+v3[i];
       v31[i] = v3[i]+v1[i];
    }
    normalize(v12);
    normalize(v23);
    normalize(v31);
    subdivideSphere2(v1, v12, v31, depth-1);
    subdivideSphere2(v2, v23, v12, depth-1);
    subdivideSphere2(v3, v31, v23, depth-1);
    subdivideSphere2(v12, v23, v31, depth-1);
}


public void drawSphere() {
    subdivideSphere2(sVdata[0], sVdata[1], sVdata[2], depth);
    subdivideSphere2(sVdata[0], sVdata[2], sVdata[4], depth);
    subdivideSphere2(sVdata[0], sVdata[4], sVdata[5], depth);
    subdivideSphere2(sVdata[0], sVdata[5], sVdata[1], depth);

    subdivideSphere2(sVdata[3], sVdata[1], sVdata[5], depth);
    subdivideSphere2(sVdata[3], sVdata[5], sVdata[4], depth);
    subdivideSphere2(sVdata[3], sVdata[4], sVdata[2], depth);
    subdivideSphere2(sVdata[3], sVdata[2], sVdata[1], depth);
 }
```

My problem is, the small spheres aren't reflecting light at all. They are very bright all the time. I can see a little bit of the light being reflected in the green lines of the cube when I move the big sphere closer to them, but no effect at all to the spheres. Also, I can't see any difference when I move the directional light (LIGHT1). I don't see any reflection on the lines of the cube, the big sphere, small spheres or the picture in the back. Below is screenshot of my program. How can I make my spheres not shine, and reflect both the directional light and the light from the big sphere? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

[image: My program]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the lightning is disabled when tracing your small spheres. I don't see the code where you call the drawSphere but it really looks like you are tracing the Big sphere with GL_LIGHTING enabled and the small spheres with GL_LIGHTING disabled.

Answer (score 0):

By reflect the light do you mean that it is illuminated? Reflection involves ray tracing and is a much bigger subject.

I don't have direct experience with JOGL but I've used jME3 a fair amount and this sort of problem there is usually caused either by using an unlit material (which doesn't seem to be the case here as you say it is being lit a bit), by bad normals on the object, or by simply having the ambient light and/or the ambient color of the material turned up too high.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell you are not setting the normals correctly. A normal should basically point into the direction you want to reflect the light to, which is usually "90° away" from the triangle (use the cross product). OpenGL will then use that normal to calculate the actual lighting reflected by the surface. See [this tutorial](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-13-normal-mapping/) for further explanation.

The other problem is that you use the outdated OpenGL 2.0 functionality, which does vertex-based lighting, so effectively each triangle in your sphere is lightened to the same value. If you are looking for per-pixel lighting, which is close to impossible using the outdated functionality unless the sphere has as many vertices as it has pixels on the screen, you need to update your code and use Shaders.

[This tutorial](http://duriansoftware.com/joe/An-intro-to-modern-OpenGL.-Table-of-Contents.html) isn't Java, but it explains the basics of modern OpenGL very well, and should be easily translatable to JOGL.